# Чему равен 1 px

Tags: android, java

Есть картинка с отсупом 100px. Какое значение нужно выставить в dp, чтобы на всех устройствах был отступ, как в оригинале? Насчет картинки понятно, нужно закидать по папкам, а насчет размеров и отступов как быть?

Comment: на каждом устройстве по-разному

Answer (score 1):

**Запомни:**

Всё очень просто, представьте себе квадрат **1х1см** (по обычной линейке нарисуйте для наглядности), так вот в этот квадрат помещаются пиксели, и их может поместиться **100х100**, **1000х1000**, **700х700** или даже так **777х888** в зависимости от реального размера пикселя (зависит от используемой матрицы)! **Всё это называется "плотность пикселей".**

> *Для расширения кругозора:*
>
> Сам пиксель, по сути, является площадкой,
> на которой располагается 3
> субпикселя, цвета у них RGB, но в
> зависимости от типа экрана субпиксели
> могут по-разному располагаться и\или
> иметь разную форму, и даже по цвету они
> могут быть не чистыми RGB...

И вот этих плотностей +100500. В Андройде все эти +100500 плотностей приблизительно усредняются в несколько "Density" (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi и т.д.). В связи с тем, что матриц экранов огромное множество, то нельзя рассчитывать на реальный фиксированный отступ.

---

> А ещё есть разные размеры экранов, как
> то мобильники, планшеты, мониторы и
> т.д.
>
> А ещё есть разные формы экранов,
> квадратные, прямоугольные, круглые...

---

**Вывод:**

Пинайте недоДизайнеров, дабы они делали резиновые макеты...

**upd для**  [[@ANDRO](/users/28075/andro)](/users/28075/andro)

есть 3 системы измерения

1. **"мм" или "см"** у которых есть
       фиксированный стандарт (линейка)
2. **"px"** пиксели - по сути единица измерения
       цифровых графических данных, но она
       не имеет привязки к "мм" или "см"
3. **"dp"** придуманная виртуальная система
       измерения, цель которой дать
       программисту что то среднее между
       "px" и "мм". Суть идеи в том, что
       "dp" на конкретном устройстве
       умножается на "Density" (его
       производители записывают в
       прошивку). В итоге получаем пусть и
       не "строго точный" размер, но всё же
       "близко приближенный"!

потому во всех фагах по андройду и говорят что размеры нужно указывать в "dp", но проблема в том что мало где разъясняется "почему".

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat,

![asd](http://snag.gy/t3EM5.jpg)

Возможно ли указать отступы для кнопки, чтобы на всех устройсвах она отображалась в 100 сверху и 10 слева? 

Если да, то напишите, пожалуйста, способ, если нет, напишите нет.

Comment: 100 чего? Пикселей - да, можно.

Comment: @ANDRO вы можете указать отступ в пикселях, но тогда реальный отступ в миллиметрах будет разным на разных матрицах (разброс будет гигантским! )


вы можете указать отступ в "dp" тогда количество dp будет умножаться на "Density", но тогда реальный отступ в миллиметрах будет разным на разных матрицах (разброс будет небольшим! но возможно для конкретного дизайна будет существенным!)

Answer (score 0):

Для начала пройдитесь по документации [Screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Пиксели не рекомендуется использовать, т.к. на разных экранах приложение будет выглядеть по-разному. 
Если присмотреться, в папке res у нас лежит несколько папок с ресурсами для разных разрешений. Каждая из этих папок имеет свой [Screen Density](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)(коэффициент плотности экрана), который отвечает за степень масштабируемости.

- low (ldpi) = 0,75
- medium (mdpi) = 1
- tv (tvdpi) = 1,33
- high (hdpi) = 1,5
- extra high (xhdpi) = 2

Т.е. на mdpi - 1px = 1dp, на xhdpi - 2px = 1dp и т.д.

Вот еще полезная ссылка для прочтения [тык](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Comment: @Nuclominus, мда, вот что значит человек зашел на сайт, даже не прочтя вопроса, уже отвечает. Я же написал, что по папкам раскидывать я умею и знаю про коофиценты, или вы хотите, чтобы я закинул в папку mpi 100 dp в hdpi 150dp))

Вопрос был в другом. Мне нужно отступ сделать, чтобы на всех экранах был 100px. Пиксели ставить нельзя, сколько dp нужно указать, чтобы они одинаково отображались, зная при этом только значение в пикселях.

Comment: @ANDRO Нисколько) Самый простой пример - ставим отступы: сверху - 100dp, слева - 10dp. На экране 1920x1200 может и будет выглядеть, так как вы задумывали. Включаем на устройстве с 480x640 и возможно приблизительно получим требуемый результат, но если компонентов много - винегрет. Если интерфейс нагружен компонентами, то кладем основной слой в ScrollView. 
Но не суть важно, в следующем ответе, человек написал все верно - "В связи с тем что матриц экранов огромное множество, то нельзя рассчитывать на реальный фиксированный отступ". Все нужно проверять самому и на всех устройствах.

Comment: @ANDRO а если нужно четко на каждом экране 100px отступа, делайте для каждого "популярного/распространенного" разрешения, свою верстку.

Comment: @Nuclominus  

> а если нужно четко на каждом экране
> 100px отступа, делайте для каждого
> "популярного/распространенного"
> разрешения, свою верстку.


это из разряда "вредные советы", никогда так не делайте!